# How do I only check 1 Div Block but not anything else

Tags: html, css

Recently I started doing a OnePager Website; I'm having trouble with this div block here "Box-Middle" and "Text-Middle":

[image: Click here for better imagination]

I want "Elektro One and Elektroinstallationen, Produkte & Kommunikationstechnik" to be vertically aligned in the white box, but I cant figure it how?

And also I want the text "Elektro One and Elektroinstallationen, Produkte & Kommunikationstechnik" to not have opacity, because it would look better

And also I wanted to do the header list all center

```css
#home {
  background-image: url(bilder/Hintergrund.jpg);
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
  box-shadow: 0 17px 53px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

#home h1,
h2 {
  margin-top: 25px;
}

#home h1 {
  margin-bottom: auto;
  color: #adadad;
}

#home h2 {
  color: #8a8a8a;
}

#Box-Middle {
  margin-top: 350px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  background: white;
}

#home #Box-Middle {
  opacity: 50%;
}
```

```html
<section id="home">
  <hr>
  <div id="Box-Middle">
    <div id="Text-Middle">
      <h1>Elektro One</h1>
      <h2>Elektroinstallationen, Produkte &amp; Kommunikationstechnik</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Note that using ids for markup / styling is not recommended. Consider using [classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Class_selectors) if possible

Comment: @volt That's subjective.

Comment: @CarlEdwards no it's not. Using ids increases specificity and makes it more difficult to maintain the project.

Comment: @volt Yes, it is subjective, even though it's a good idea in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the `div` that contains what you want to center:

In this case: `#Box-Middle`

```
display: flex;
align-items: center;
```

As for the Header list, wrap it around a `div` and set its text-aling to `center`:

```
.header-list {text-align: center;}
```

Comment: Hello! Thank you but I have a question what do you mean by wrap it around a div?

Comment: Hello! you didn't add the code of the header so I couldn't exemplify. What I mean is you add a div with class "header-list " (or any other name) around the code of your header. Add to the text-align class: text-align: center;